# use react-native-spalsh screen with react-native-navigation on Android

Tags: android, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I upgraded react-native-navigation from v1 to v6. It used to be possible on v1 to use both `react-native-spalsh-screen` and `react-native-navigation` (on Android) – is it still possible? Not sure how to handle it on the MainActivity.java

(in the past, I made it extend `SplashActivity` (of `com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Playground sets a splash screen in [MainActivity](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/playground/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/playground/MainActivity.java#L18). This is actually the best way to set a splash screen as it doesn't rely on React Native startup.

Comment: Thank you! So you mean I should just remove the `react-native-splash-screen` dependency?

Comment: Yes exactly. Remove `react-native-splash-screen` as it's inferior to setting a splash screen in native.